# Python MySQL insert and retrieve a list in Blob

Tags: python, mysql, string, list, blob

I'm trying to insert a list of element into a MySQL database (into a Blob column). This is an example of my code is:

```
myList = [1345,22,3,4,5]
myListString = str(myList)
myQuery = 'INSERT INTO table (blobData) VALUES (%s)'
cursor.execute(query, myListString)
```

Everything works fine and I have my list stored in my database. But, when I want to retrieve my list, because it's now a string I have no idea how to get a real integer list instead of a string.

For example, if now i do :

```
myQuery = 'SELECT blobData FROM db.table'
cursor.execute(myQuery)
myRetrievedList = cursor.fetch_all()
print myRetrievedList[0]
```

I ll get :

```
[
```

instead of :

```
1345
```

Is there any way to transform my string [1345,22,3,4,5] into a list ?

Answer (score 1):

As per the comments in this answer, the OP has a list of lists being entered as the blob field. In that case, the JSON seems a better way to go.

```
import json
...
...
myRetrievedList = cursor.fetch_all()
jsonOfBlob = json.loads(myRetrievedList)
integerListOfLists = []
for oneList in jsonOfBlob:
  listOfInts = [int(x) for x in oneList]
  integerListOfLists.append(listOfInts)

return integerListOfLists #or print, or whatever
```

Comment: your solution seems great but I have 1 little problem. I lied to make the problem look easier, in reality I have a list of list. So myList = [[1245, 22, 3, 4, 5] [1,2,3,4,5]]. What should I do then ?

Answer (score 1):

You have to pick a data format for your list, common solutions in order of my preference are:

- `json` -- fast, readable, allows nested data, very useful if your table is ever used by any other system. checks if blob is valid format. use `json.dumps()` and `json.loads()` to convert to and from string/blob representation
- `repr()` -- fast, readable, works across Python versions. unsafe if someone gets into your db. user `repr()` and `eval()` to get data to and from string/blob format
- `pickle` -- fast, unreadable, does not work across multiple architectures (afaik). does not check if blob is truncated. use `cPickle.dumps(..., protocol=(cPickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL))` and `cPickle.loads(...)` to convert your data.